# core data and relationship predicate

Tags: swift, core-data, relationship, predicate

I've start swift & core data few month ago usually I've found my answer on this website but for the first time I'm really stuck with "Relationship" and "Predicates"

I've created a first view controller with a tableview which is populated by the user and this part is working like I wish. 
The user can "tap" a cell and open a new view controller with a new tableview and I'd like populate this tableview with data that in relation with the cell the user tapped.

I'm using CoreData and I've set 2 entities : "Compte" and "Operation" they are in relationship by ONE TO MANY (ONE compte for MANY operation)

Here where I am :

- when the user tap the cell i'm using segue to send the "Compte" to the second view controller :

  //Segue

  ```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

      let guest = segue.destination as! OperationsViewController
      let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
      let operation = fetchedResultController.object(at: indexPath!)
      guest.compteTestRelation = operation
  }
  ```
- In the `OperationsViewController` i've set this variable :

  ```
  var compteTestRelation: Compte!
  ```
- for testing my data I've create a FOR LOOP like this and a FUNCTION:

  ```
  for index in 1 ... 10 {

      let newOp = Operation(context: context)
      newOp.nom = "Test Compte \(index)"
      newOp.date = NSDate()
      newOp.moyenPaiement = "Test"

      compteTestRelation.addToRelationCompte(newOp) // RelationShip
  }

  do {
      try context.save()
  } catch {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
  }
  ```
- the FUNCTION

  ```
  func displayOperation() {

      if let opList = compteTestRelation.relationCompte as? Set<Operation> {

          sortedOperationArray = opList.sorted(by: { (operationA:Operation, operationB:Operation) -> Bool in
              return operationA.date!.compare(operationB.date! as Date) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
          })
      print(sortedOperationArray)
      }
  }
  ```

In the console with "print" It work like I wish depend the cell is tapped the print(sortedOperationArray) appear or not

My problem now is how populate my tableview with this data, when I use predicates in my FetchResultController I've got error or an empty tableview but in the console everything seems to work so I'm thinking the relationship is OK ..

If I don't use PREDICATE I can populate my tableview with the data but I see always ALL the data

I've seen other similar problems and answers on stackoverflow.com but nothing work for the moment.

Thank You! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an another way to predicate my data and it works for me now

I've create a new attribute in my OPERATION entity called "id" and when I create my data I attribute an ID like this :

```
for index in 1 ... 10 {

let newOp = Operation(context: context)
newOp.nom = "Test Compte \(index)"
newOp.date = NSDate()
newOp.moyenPaiement = "Test"
newOp.id = "id123\(compteTestRelation.nom!)"

compteTestRelation.addToRelationCompte(newOp) // RelationShip
}

do {
try context.save()
} catch {
print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

then I predicate my data like this in my FetchResultController :

```
func setupFetchedResultController () {

    let operationsRequest: NSFetchRequest<Operation> = Operation.fetchRequest()
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nom", ascending: true)
    let keyPath = "id"
    let searchString = "id123\(compteTestRelation.nom!)"
    let operationsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS %@", keyPath, searchString)

    operationsRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    operationsRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    operationsRequest.predicate = operationsPredicate


    fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: operationsRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    do {
        try fetchedResultController.performFetch()

    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```